# Date Picker is getting force close on SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity, android-datepicker

Here is my code, it's not showing any error. When i try to run it's getting closed, `ClassCastException`.

**NOTE:THE SAME CODE IS WORKING WHEN EXTENDING TO SherlockFragment**

```
public class EventsFeatured extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
TextView cal;
View view;

int year;
int month;
int day;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_featured, container, false);
    iniitialize();

    return view;
}

private void iniitialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = t.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = t.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = t.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCalendar);
    cal.setText(new StringBuilder()
    .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
    .append(year).append(" "));
}
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because in your `TabsAdapter`'s `getItem()` method you're trying to create a `Fragment`(`SherlockFragment`) from a class that isn't a `Fragment` (as the `getItem()` method expects), that class is a `SherlockFragmentActivity`.

Why do you need `EventsFeatured` to extend `SherlockFragmentActivity` when from the looks of it(and how you use it) that class should be extending `SherlockFragment`? For example you have the `onCreateView()` method in `EventsFeatured` which it's just a simple method, it's not the callback method of a Fragment in which the `Fragment`'s view is created.

If you need activities as tabs you need to use a `TabActivity`(but, which you shouldn't use as it's deprecated).